# Firebase (Realtime database), могут ли списать деньги за большой трафик?

Tags: база-данных, github, firebase, realtime

Есть петпроект использующий Realtime database, он на гитхабе (видно все url запросов в файлах) + гитхаб пейдж развернут. Если будет условно очень много запросов на чтение\запись за день (или из-за ошибки например зацикленной), или ушлый "хацкер" начнет что-то делать, в теории возможно что с бесплатного тарифа перекинет на долг? Или просто дб закроется (тк лимит по запросам на день) и опять заработает с завтрашнего дня?

Тариф Spark (бесплатный). Интересуюсь с позиции, что некоторые проекты хочется сделать - выложить - забыть о них, и не аукнется ли мне это в будущем)